# What does: "bad argument #-1 to 'newLine' (Proxy expected, got nil) mean

Tags: proxy, lua, coronasdk

I have been working on a game. The game involves (one part) getting the x and y positions of a touch event, and tracking it when it moves and adding the x/y values to a table. I have that down pat. However when I try and create a line from the table it gives me this error:

```
/Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Programing/Lua Projects/When Balls Drop/main.lua:21: bad argument #-1 to 'newLine' (Proxy expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'newLine'
    /Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Programing/Lua Projects/When Balls Drop/main.lua:21: in function </Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Programing/Lua Projects/When Balls Drop/main.lua:8>
    ?: in function <?:221>
```

I have no idea what that does...

The code in question, with the line commented.

```
function drawLineTouchListener( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        currx = event.x
        curry = event.y
        table.insert( linePositions, currx)
        table.insert( linePositions, curry)
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        currx = event.x
        curry = event.y
        table.insert( linePositions, currx)
        table.insert( linePositions, curry)
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        -- This is where the code does't work.
        line = display.newLine( linePositions )
        test = {
        0, 0,
        20, 20,
        40, 40, 
        60, 60, 
        80, 80}

        line2 = display.newLine( test)
        line2:setStrokeColor( black )
    end
    print( "x: "..currx.."  y:"..curry)
end
```

Here is all my code:

```
    -- Hides the status bar at the top of the screen
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

print("App Starting!")

linePositions = {}

function drawLineTouchListener( event )

    if event.phase == "began" then
        currx = event.x
        curry = event.y
        table.insert( linePositions, currx)
        table.insert( linePositions, curry)
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        currx = event.x
        curry = event.y
        table.insert( linePositions, currx)
        table.insert( linePositions, curry)
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        line = display.newLine( linePositions )
        test = {
        0, 0,
        20, 20,
        40, 40, 
        60, 60, 
        80, 80}

        line2 = display.newLine( test)
        line2:setStrokeColor( black )
    end


    print( "x: "..currx.."  y:"..curry)

end

function playButtonTouch ( event )

    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    end
end

function highScoreButtonTouch ( event )

    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    end
end

function quitButtonTouch ( event )

    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        os.exit(0)
    end
end


function displayMenu ()
    mainMenuGroup = display.newGroup()

    title = display.newImage(mainMenuGroup, "Title.png", display.contentCenterX, 20) 
    title:scale( .3, .3 )

    playButton = display.newImage(mainMenuGroup, "Play Button.png", display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 300)
    playButton:scale( .3, .3 )

    quitButton = display.newImage(mainMenuGroup, "Quit Button.png", display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 200)
    quitButton:scale( .3, .3 )

    highScoreButton = display.newImage(mainMenuGroup, "Highscore Button.png", display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 100)
    highScoreButton:scale( .3, .3 )

    playButton:addEventListener( "touch", playButtonTouch )

    quitButton:addEventListener( "touch", quitButtonTouch )

    highScoreButton:addEventListener( "touch", highScoreButtonTouch )
end


--Creates a solid white background that doubles for a touch listner
background = display.newRect( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight+100)
background:setFillColor(1, 1, 1 )

background:addEventListener( "touch", drawLineTouchListener )

displayMenu()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`display.newLine`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newLine.html)?

Comment: @greatwolf Yes, all i got from it was how to create a line with predefined points. Ex: local myLine = display.newLine( 0,0, 100,100 ). And that you cannot tap on them...

Comment: try `unpack(linePositions)` and passing that to `display.newLine`.

Comment: @greatwolf Works like a charm. Thank you. (you should add it into a solution with a bit of an explanation) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you're passing a *table* when the function expects individual arguments.

Instead, use `unpack(linePositions)` which will "*unpack*" everything in table (by returning it as a tuple).

**Note** that in *Lua 5.2* and later, it's table.unpack.